# Custom Slot from qt4 design generated h file

Tags: c++, qt4, qt4.8

Hi Im try to make a custom slot with the h file that qt4 designer generated
I see how the standard slot is made but i would like to, "once past learning this step" have run terminal commands and have it output in the text box so im tryin to replace the past() slot with one i can right commands in
Here is the h file file that works great but.... the above problem'' trying to understand the flow.. 2nd day so any pointers are awsome. so here it is i will comment where i think i should be working.. but have had no success all day lol.

```
#ifndef SWEETGUIFORMQ19488_H
#define SWEETGUIFORMQ19488_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QTextEdit>
#include <QtGui/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_SweetGuiForm
{
public:
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_2;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox;

    void setupUi(QWidget *SweetGuiForm)
    {
        if (SweetGuiForm->objectName().isEmpty())
            SweetGuiForm->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("SweetGuiForm"));
        SweetGuiForm->resize(511, 275);
        verticalLayout_2 = new QVBoxLayout(SweetGuiForm);
        verticalLayout_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"));
        verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        verticalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("verticalLayout"));
        textEdit = new QTextEdit(SweetGuiForm);
        textEdit->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("textEdit"));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(textEdit);

        buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(SweetGuiForm);
        buttonBox->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("buttonBox"));
        buttonBox->setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);


        verticalLayout_2->addLayout(verticalLayout);

        QWidget::setTabOrder(textEdit, buttonBox);

        retranslateUi(SweetGuiForm);
        QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), SweetGuiForm, SLOT(close()));
```

ok here i guess i could replace the paste() with on_buttonBox_accepted(), please correct me i really am still quessing at this point but where do i right the function? do i do the in a file called sweetguiform.cpp ? this is where im lost.. help..
            QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), textEdit, SLOT(paste()));

```
        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(SweetGuiForm);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *SweetGuiForm)
    {
        SweetGuiForm->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("SweetGuiForm", "Form", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};
namespace Ui {
    class SweetGuiForm: public Ui_SweetGuiForm {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // SWEETGUIFORMQ19488_H
```

Is this the way to do things when brand new?

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't be editing the header file that Qt generates for you. Instead, you should write your own header/implementation file that includes this auto-generated header and sets up the signal-slot connections there. For example:

```
#include "ui_SweetGuiForm.h"

class SweetGuiForm : public QWidget
{
public:
    SweetGuiForm( ): ui( new Ui::SweetGuiForm )
    {
        ui->setupUi( this );
    }

public slots:
    void on_buttonBox_accepted( )
    {
        // your code here
    }

protected:
    Ui::SweetGuiForm* ui;
};
```

Qt will find the `on_buttonBox_accepted` method and set up the signal-slot connection for you, so you don't have to call `QObject::connect`.